# In SQL, how to show values which do not have an equal value?

Tags: sql

So for SQL, I have a data set in which there are values which do not have an equal value when I do an outer join. I would like to do an SQL where it shows the values that do not have a corresponding value. Normally I do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB ON tableA.ID = tableB.ID
```

I would like to ONLY see the values that don't have `tableA.ID = tableB.ID`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Lots of row pairs have inequalities, and that probably isn't really what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tableA a LEFT JOIN tableB b on a.ID = b.ID 
where b.ID is null
```